# How to change css rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using Rails admin. I have a model named `Order`. The `Order` model has a `Description` field. When I look at the list of orders in the rails admin, the description fields of the `orders` are not completely showing. Only a portion of text and ellipsis is shown up.

Example: `Some information about ordering ...`.

How to show the `Description` displayed completely without cutting?

```
config.model Orders do

  list do
    filters [:status, :created_at]
    field :created_at do
      label "Request date"
      strftime_format "%b %d, %l:%M%P %Y"
    end
    field :description
    field :status

    field :scheduled_date do
      strftime_format "%a %b, %d"
    end

    field :address do
      filterable false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you currently have?

Comment: Also, could you please share the corresponding css code?

Comment: I do not add any spetsalno css. Simply installed rails admin, and it uses its default css.

Comment: Could you please try and see if my answer below fixes your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to increase the length for the `description` field this way:

```
field :description, :text do
  html_attributes do
    {:maxlength => 600}
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you try using 'Order' but not 'Orders'. Model name in Rails should be singular.

Comment: @VladIsildy I have updated my answer. Now it works. I have tested it with a sample rails app and it can accommodate bigger texts for description. You can see the sample app here: https://github.com/rakibulislam/rails_order_test_app
Here is the code that you require to change the length of your Order model's description field: https://github.com/rakibulislam/rails_order_test_app/blob/master/app/models/product.rb#L9-L13